# perl manipulate binary string with bitwise not operator

Tags: perl

Suppose I have a string in perl.

```
$a = "001010";
```

After manipulating a bitwise not operator, the result should be

```
~$a = "110101";
```

How can I do this in perl?

Comment: Convert the string to a number; do your bitwise manipulation; then convert it back to a string.  Look at the pack()/unpack() functions (`perldoc -f pack`) for details on doing those conversions.

Comment: Indeed. It's pretty weird to be doing bit arithmetic on the binary representation of a number rather than on the number itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `oct` and `sprintf`:

```
 $a = sprintf("%0".(length($a))."b", (~oct("0b".$a)) & (1 << length($a)) - 1);
```

Comment: Readability score: 0. (Not that readability counts for much in Perl :))

Comment: Also, it fails for long bit strings.

Answer (score 8):

Or just using `tr///`:

```
$str =~ tr/01/10/;
```

Comment: this is the simplest way, IMO

Answer (score 2):

One solution is using a regex:

```
$a = "001010";

$a =~ s/([01])/1-$1/eg;
```

Answer (score 0):

There Is More Than One Way To Do It:

```
$str = join '' => map 0+!$_, split //, $str;
```